# SVG doesn´t show up

Tags: html, css, object, svg, embed

This is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME | index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -->
</head>
<body>                       
    <div style="text-align:center;padding:150px 0;">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/menu.svg">
            <!-- <embed src="/img/menu.svg"> -->
        </object>
    </div>                
</body>
```

And this is the SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 228.4 18.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 228.4 18.2;" xml:space="preserve" width="500px" height="500px">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{
            fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:10;stroke-miterlimit:10;
        }
    </style>
    <line id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" x1="5.8" y1="10" x2="221.8" y2="10"/>
</svg>
```

Same result if I use *embed src*.
The SVG is just a stroke, and doesn't show up with any browsers (firefox, chrome, edge). I am new with SVG images.

Comment: Do you know how to look for sources in the dev tools? You should first see if the file is being loaded and you can see it from there

Comment: Yes I do. Just the HTML file is loaded. I am wondering if it is a width-height problem.

Comment: If the image isn't even loading you may have a problem with your file path. Would you try doing it with an img tag? An try to check the path?

Comment: SOLVED!
Using the `<img>` tag and moving the SVG to the main folder instead of the /img one. You were right, it was a file path problem also.